# yii2 gridview no pagination wont work on more than 3 thousand records

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, pagination, yii2

when I click on the action of a controller and i disable pagination, the web page won't load...
the problem is when i click on the action controller which is some sort of:

```
public function actionMyview(){
return $this->render("//myview/index");
}
```

in the view code I'm making some sort of MVVM (i'm calling the ActiveDataProvider into it):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use frontend\models\myModel;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
$dataProvider2 = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => myModel::find(),
            'pagination' => false,
        ]);

$this->title = 'Listing 3 thousand records';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="ventas-model-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create manually a new record', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4']) ?>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search-criteria" placeholder="please write a text in order to search" width=""/>

    </div>
    <span class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">&nbsp;</span>
        <?php

$this->registerJs("
var rows = jQuery('.table tr');
$('#search-criteria').keyup(function() {
    var val = jQuery.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = jQuery(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
",
    View::POS_END,
    'ventanamodal001');
         ?>
    </p>

    <?php echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider2,        
        'columns' => [
            [
                            'attribute' => 'date',
                            'format' => ['date', 'php:d/m/Y']
                        ], 
            ["label"=>'First Column',"attribute"=>"first","value"=>function($data0){
                return myModel::aBolivares($data0->first);

            }],
            ["label"=>'second Column',"attribute"=>'second',"value"=>function($data0){
                return myModel::aBolivares($data0->second);
            }],

            ["label"=>"totals","value"=>function($data0){
                $totals=$data0->first+$data0->secod;
                return myModel::aBolivares($totals);
            },"format"=>"html","enableSorting"=>true,"attribute"=>"first"],
            ['label'=>'description',
            'value'=>function ($data){                
                return empty($data->Observ)?" ":"<p class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></p>";
            },
            "format"=>"html","attribute"=>"Observ"],            
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

the code sample will iterate into a yii2 ActiveDataProvider object given to the yii\grid\GridView;... when I upload into a remote location it will fail: (I'm using HostGator shared hosting).

IT'S IMPORTANT TO SAY: IT WILL FAIL WHEN GIVEN MORE THAN 3 THOUSAND RECORDS == 3000 records directly from DB. If you use let's say 1500 records it will slow down but will work... only when injecting a high volume of records will fail...

Comment: i have the instruction to not to use pagination at alll... it requires to show all the records from DB, which are nearly >3000

Comment: but in localhost it's working OK... but when go to remote it'll crash... i thought it would be some problem with memory size...

Comment: dont go please... let me try the following:
memory_limit = 256M (MAXIMUM)
max_execution_time = 30 (MAXIMUM in seconds)
max_input_time = 60 (MAXIMUM in seconds)
post_max_size = 64M (MAXIMUM) 
upload_max_filesize = 64M (MAXIMUM) 
this is taken from https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/php-settings-that-cannot-be-changed

Comment: i incresed the memory... try to use another way... and still getting the same error... changing default values is still getting problems

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out

The server didn't respond in time.

Comment: the user wants to view all data... it's his/her/their desire... but i'm thinking that i could cache the activeDataProvider... i'm trying to do it... but i cant figure it out...  cache is the solution but dont know how to implement it

Comment: do you have an idea how could i cache all data in yii2 ???

Comment: still waiting for a solution...